# Patient Search in FHIR (Hapi) is Case sensitive when searched query based on Email

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi

I am new to FHIR. I am working on patient search on FHIR but noticed the patient search with email in query parameter is Case sensitive (search is insensitive on family, given).

Here is a sample patient found with the below query.

`https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient?family=Hello&telecom:contains=hi_updated@gmail.com`

Now when I search with different case server is not returning the data.

`https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Patient?family=Hello&telecom:contains=Hi_updated@gmail.com`

Could some one help me how can I specify in the query to make search as case insensitive.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The 'telecom' search parameter is of type 'token'. This uses case sensitive and exact matching by default. It searches for any kind of telecom details, which could also be a phone number - in that case you probable expect the more precise matching. For email addresses, you can also use the 'email' search parameter. However, that also is of type 'token' so it will not resolve your issue.

On your own server, you may be able to override the default search parameter to be of type 'string' instead. A string type search is not case sensitive by default.

Comment: Hello @Mirjam, Thank you for the reply. Can you Please elaborate more on how to make a string type search for email. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You would have to change the SearchParameter for the email search, and make sure your server uses that. HAPI should be able to do that automatically when you upload the new SearchParameter to it, I think. Download the FHIR definitions: http://hl7.org/fhir/downloads.html, open the search parameters file to find the current one for email (http://hl7.org/fhir/SearchParameter/individual-email), and change 'token' to 'string' in the type field. Then upload the SearchParameter.

Comment: Hello @Mirjam, I was also going through [Fhir docs](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#token) where they mention that we can use CodeSystem.caseSensitive for token search  to specify case Insensitive but I am able to find the right examples to use it.

Comment: That would only apply to a CodeSystem and then the values coming out of that, provided the implementation looks at that field. So it's of no use to email addresses. As you can read, the server could choose to match on the email case-insensitive, so you could reach out to the developers to see if they can change the behaviour. Or if you are in control of the implementation, you can change it yourself.

Comment: Hello @Mirjam, thank you for your reply. I believe the Identity search in patient resource is also case sensitive search because identity is of a token type. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, it is. You can see the type of the search parameters in the table at the bottom of each resource type page. Usually any code or identifier search is of type token. Searching the technical identity is possible as well with the '_id' parameter. This is listed on the http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html page. The types for the parameters listed there is in the paragraph http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#standard.